# How to remove tracks limit from wonderplugin audio player

Tags: wordpress, html5-audio

The free version of Wonderplugin audio player allow only three tracks, is there any way I can override the limitation? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the best solution is to buy the plugin I think. Or choose another one.

Comment: It's too expensive for me. Can you please recommend one for me? Something alternative to wonderplugin audio player

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

- Open `wonderplugin-audio\app\wonderplugin-audio-creator.js`
- Find string `wonderplugin_audio_config.slides.length>=3` and change `3` to `9999999`

Step 2

- Open `wonderplugin-audio\engine\wonderpluginaudio.js`
- Find string `instance.elemLength>3` and change `3` to `9999999`
- Find string `instance.elemLength=3;instance.elemArray.length=3` and change all `3` to `9999999`

Comment: Thanks.. I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: Please, make my answer as a silution if it was helpful. Thanks.